# How to replace a particular string found in URL taken from console with file content found on each line written in text file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, replace, uri

I want to replace fuzz word which has been written in URL taken from console with contents of text file having one string per line.
After replacing this fuzz word with file content want to fire http request with this replaced content file and store responses with modified requests in new file.

I have written like this but getting error:

```
fuzz1.rb:16: private method `gsub' called for #<URI::HTTP:0x2969040> (NoMethodError)
```

Code is here:

```
require 'net/http'

puts "Enter Target:\n"
target = URI(gets())
new_reference = target
a1 = target.clone
Net::HTTP.start(target.host, target.port) do |http|
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new target.request_uri
response = http.request request 
puts response.body
end
puts "File contents:\n"
f= File.open("fuzz.txt","r")
while line = f.gets do
    puts "Attack value: #{line}"
    b = a1.gsub('fuzz','#{line}')
    c = b
    Net::HTTP.start(c.host, c.port) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new c.request_uri
    response = http.request request 
    puts response.body
    end
end
```

No idea why this gsub error is coming and not replacing fuzz word found in URL with file line content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a1` is an URI object, it doesn't have a `gsub` method. You need to cast it to a string. Try this

```
    b = URI.parse(a1.to_s.gsub('fuzz','#{line}'))
```

Comment: Then result of your replace is not a valid URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is working fine but after getting this how can I convert this string to URL again and perform same thing that I did in code snippet attached above? Net::HTTP.start(target.host, target.port) do |http|
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new target.request_uri
response = http.request request 
puts response.body
end

Comment: If it's a valid URI string, call `URI.parse` on it. If it's not a valid URI string, what result do you expect?

Comment: its working fine now as you told. but need to store all this in  new file. I am able to print all request and response with file contents replaced in URL. But how to store it in new file?

Comment: Use `File.write filename, content`

Comment: After writing this loop I am able to store console output , only first request and response in new textfile but not others: `while line = f.gets do puts "Attack value: #{line}" newuri = a.to_s.gsub('fuzz',"#{line}") print "New URL with attack value: \n#{newuri} \n" nuri = URI.parse("#{newuri}") puts "Attacking with value: #{line}" Net::HTTP.start(nuri.host, nuri.port) do |http| request = Net::HTTP::Get.new nuri.request_uri response = http.request request puts response.body $stdout = File.new('result.txt', 'w') end` using this $stdout, but not able to store whole console output for all requests